# Best strategy for including JavaScript in MVC partials. Advice please

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for a bit of advice please. I'm developing a reasonably large ASP.NET MVC 3 app.

There are hundreds of partials throughout the system, so that I can break down the application in to composable chunks. Many partials contains various JQuery or straight Javascript script blocks.

The problem is that each time a partial is included in a main page, the script block will obviously be included each time, which is not the desired effect, clearly.

I could put the scripts in the main page, but there are often lots of long, detailed scripts and I don't want to clutter the page if the scripts aren't needed. (Some times the partials can appear ZERO or more times).

What's the recommended approach that would allow the script block to be included IF and ONLY if a partial is included in the page AND also included it only once?

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: MVC4 has script bundling features, but since you're using MVC3, I'd look in to RequireJS, which should allow you to modularize your scripts in the same way partial views modularize your HTML. http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your swift reply. I'll look in to requirejs.org straight away, but you've actually just given me the inspiration to roll my own! My thinking is, if I create an extension, such as Html.RegisterScript(script or scriptfile), this could save the script in a de-duped array in ViewData. Then, in my master layout, I simply render the scripts from the ViewData array. Hmmm, sounds like a plan! Thanks once again.

Comment: @Simon If I understand it well. Your plan is to save some values in partial view to ViewData and then read it in master layout. It won't work because each partial view gets its own local copy of ViewData and any changes to it cannot be read in outer view.

Comment: @mipe34 thanks for your reply. I wasn't aware of that limitation. I guess the theory is ok but the storage medium will need some more research then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a situation similar to this; a large MVC3 app with numerous partials (containing their own scripts).  The approach I took was to namespacing the objects.  You could namespace your partial view scripts, then do a check when the partial loads to detect if the namespace is there or if it needs to be created:

```
if(window.AppName.Module == undefined){
   //Do initialization
   window.AppName.Module = {};
   //Call init or whatever here
}
//Else continue on...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this module to your partials.

```
(function (appname, undefined){

    // use appName object here ..

})(window.AppName = window.AppName || {});
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion too, very similar approach to TNCodeMonkey's. Thanks.